# Using LWP in Perl how to transfer the cookies to a browser

Tags: perl

Consider a site having 10 pages(like shopcart process) and login.
I need to browse upto 5 pages using Perl LWP, then
transfer the cookies and sessions to a browser like Chrome and then 
continue till the 10th page there, without giving the login info again.
Is this possible ?
If so please direct me on this...

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. If using a different browser than Chromium, store your LWP cookie jar with [HTTP-Cookies](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Cookies/) or [HTTP-Cookies-Opera](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Cookies-Opera/).

If using Chromium, you have to program this on your own. The store is a straight-forward Sqlite3 database.

```
$ echo .schema | sqlite3 ~/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies
CREATE TABLE cookies (creation_utc INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,host_key TEXT NOT NULL,name TEXT NOT NULL,value TEXT NOT NULL,path TEXT NOT NULL,expires_utc INTEGER NOT NULL,secure INTEGER NOT NULL,httponly INTEGER NOT NULL,last_access_utc INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,value LONGVARCHAR);
CREATE INDEX cookie_times ON cookies (creation_utc);
```

I can recommend [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://p3rl.org/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader) for accessing it.